# Continuous Bivariate Random Variable, Conditional Probability Problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to study Bivariate Random Variables. The question is

if joint pdf is given by 
$$ f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
8xy & 0<x<1 \hspace{2mm}\text{ and }\hspace{2mm}  0<y<x  \\ 
 0 &\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

then what is the value of $P(Y < \frac{1}{8} | X < \frac{1}{2} ) $?

I tried solving it by the method

$$ P\left(Y < \frac{1}{8} \biggm| X < \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{P(Y < \frac{1}{8} , X< \frac{1}{2} )}{P(X<\frac{1}{2})}$$

$$ = \frac{ \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{8}}{f(x,y)\,dy\,dx}  }{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)\,dx}  $$

The answer I get is $\frac{1}{2^3}$

The answer in the book is $\frac{31}{256}$

As far as I know the above method is the correct way to calculate the answer.

Comment: Why are you sure that the method you use is correct? It is unclear what you mean with $\frac{1}{8}\! /X$. Is it $8/X$? As long as you not make clear what you mean here, no help is possible IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $$\frac{\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^{\min(x,\frac{1}{8})}{f(x,y)\,dy\,dx}  }{\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^{x}{f(x,y)\,dy\,dx}}$$ though you may find the calculation easier if you split the numerator into $$\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{1}{8}}\int_0^{x}{f(x,y)\,dy\,dx}+\int_{\frac{1}{8}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{8}}{f(x,y)\,dy\,dx} $$

Answer (score 2):

The catch is that you have to ensure $y$ is less than *both* $1/8$ and $x$.

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Y<1/8, X<1/2) & = \int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{\min(x, 1/8)} f(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname dx
\\
& = \int_0^{1/8}\int_0^x f(x,y)\operatorname dy\operatorname dx+\int_{1/8}^{1/2}\int_0^{1/8} f(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x
\end{align}$